# Is there a way to set axis tick label in ggplot as a constant value?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I actually would like to use this in a Shiny app, but I think this is in common a R problem.

In simple, I am wondering if I could set a constant axis tick label no matter what the input value is.

For example:

```
x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
y1 = [100, 200, 300, 400]
y2 = [500, 600, 700, 800]

fig1 <- ggplot() + geom_line(x1, y1)
fig2 <- ggplot() + geom_line(x2, y2)
```

I tried to let the x-ticks only display three strings as `c("Mark", "John", "Andy")`, but did not find a good way.

I know we can use `break` and `label` in `scale_x_continuous` to do the similar things, but I am wondering if there is a universal way for accommodating either `fig1` or `fig2`. That is, I don't need to worry about what the `x` value is, and it would always show `"Mark", "John", "Andy"` for x-ticks label.

Does anyone know any tricks for achieving this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `labels` in `scale_x_continuous` the universal solution?

```r
library(ggplot2)

x1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
x2 = c(5, 6, 7, 8)
y1 = c(100, 200, 300, 400)
y2 = c(500, 600, 700, 800)
marks <- c("Mark", "John", "Andy", "Weee")
ggplot() + 
    geom_line(aes(x1, y1)) +
    scale_x_continuous(labels = marks)
ggplot() + 
    geom_line(aes(x2, y2)) +
    scale_x_continuous(labels = marks)
```

Make sure `x1` and `x2` must have the same length as `marks`

[image]
[image]